# Create a new UV map but move the textures with the polygons?

Tags: uv

I've imported an object from an 3d data capture program in Blender, which came with an automatically generated UV Map. I'd like to create a new (more sensible) UV map based on the cleaned-up geometry, but keep the model looking the same (so the polygon-to-pixel-colour mapping is consistent).

Is this at all possible to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

If the two UV maps reside on the same mesh you can use UV baking. If you create a material with the texture and the first uv layer, you can bake the diffuse color (or even the rendered result, if you make a shadeless material) and bake it to the second UV layer. Make sure to select the proper UV layers in the material texture slot, UV editor and active UV layer.